# Unmittelbarkeit des Todes beim „Tottreten“ oder „Totfahren“

Tags: meaning

In meiner Frage geht es zwar um eine traurige Sache, aber ich möchte sie hier trotzdem stellen, weil mich der sprachliche Aspekt interessiert.

**Sachverhalt:**

In der Überschrift eines Zeitungsartikel las ich, dass ein Hund *totgetreten* wurde.

Im Text des Artikels stand, dass der Hund *getreten* wurde und *einige Zeit später an den Folgen verstarb*.

**Frage:**

Für mich bedeutete *tottreten* bisher, dass solange zugetreten wird, bis der Tod unmittelbar eintritt. Mit anderen Worten: der Vorgang des Tretens wäre erst nach Eintritt des Todes abgeschlossen. Wenn dem so ist, wäre die Überschrift des Artikels nicht korrekt, denn dort war es eher so etwas wie eine schwere Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge (mir ist klar, dass es das bei Hunden nicht gibt, aber mir geht es hier nicht um den rechtlichen sondern um den sprachlichen Aspekt).

---

**Edit 1:**
Angeregt durch Manuel Jordans und äöüs Antworten sind mir noch zwei vergleichbare Beispiele eingefallen, nämlich das *Totfahren* und das *Sattessen*.

Wurde jemand *totgefahren*, auch wenn er erst Tage, vielleicht sogar Wochen, Monate oder gar Jahre, nach einem Verkehrsunfall verstirbt? Oder ist das Wort nicht vielleicht nur dann angebracht, wenn jemand unmittelbar *beim* Verkehrsunfall ums Leben kam?

Hat sich jemand *satt gegessen*, auch wenn sein Sättigungsgefühl erst einige Zeit nach der Mahlzeit eingetreten ist? Oder kann man sich nicht vielmehr nur dadurch *satt essen*, indem man *solange isst, bis man satt ist*?

---

**Edit 2:** Ich merke, dass der Inhalt, der mit den Wörtern *totgetreten* und *totgefahren* einhergeht, anscheinend starke Emotionen bei einigen hervorruft. Das lässt sich aber leider kaum vermeiden, wenn man den Gebrauch der Wörter anhand von Beispielen erklären möchte. Es geht mir hier nicht um den Inhalt der Beispiele an sich – wer wann was tat und wie lange genau etwas dauerte: diese Dinge sind irrelevant für den sprachlichen Aspekt.

Comment: Wie hättest du die Schlagzeile geschrieben? "Hund an den Folgen von Tritten verstorben"?

Comment: für "zu Tode getreten" sagt man kurz "totgetreten"

Comment: @tofro: Je nach Publikationsziel: "Hund erliegt Trittverletzungen", "Hund nach Tritten verendet", "Hund stirbt nach Tritten" oder "Tödliche Tritt-Attacke: Darum musste dieser kleine Hund sterben".

Comment: Was ist denn "einige Zeit später"? 3 Jahre, 3 Wochen, 3 Tage, auf dem Weg zum Tierarzt, während jemand den Tierarzt anrief?

Comment: Wenn ich jemandend totschieße, muss er ja auch nicht sofort tot sein. Trotzdem ist der Schuss verantwortlch für den Tod.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Außer bei dem Beispiel _grün- und blauschlagen_ sehe ich es bei allen anderen hier aufgeführten Beispielen doch genauso wie bei _tottreten_. Ob _tottreten_, _totfahren_, _totschießen_, _sattessen_, _wachrütteln_, _gesundpflegen_ oder was auch immer - bisher war ich immer der Meinung, dass bei einem Kompositum aus Zustand und Handlungsverb die Handlung solange gehen würde, bis der Zustand eingetreten wäre.

Comment: @Björn: Das ist dann deine Meinung. Tottreten, totfahren usw deuten nur Ursache (treten, fahren, usw) und Wirkung (Tod) an. Die Unmittelbarkeit oder das Persistieren bis die Wirkung eintritt sind nirgendwo gegeben. Man mag das zwar so fühlen, aber das ist ja nicht entscheidend. Gerade bei Totfahren gilt das auch. Derjenige lebt oft noch einige Zeit bevor der Tod entritt. Und trotzdem kann man es ruhigen Gewissens Totfahren nennen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Danke für die Erklärung, ich denke darüber nach.

Comment: Wieso soll es schwere Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge bei Hunden nicht geben? Einen Körper haben Hunde doch unstreitig. Den kann man verletzen. Die Verletzung kann leicht oder schwer sein. Die Folge der schweren Verletzung der Tod. Es gibt keinen Paragraphen für den Sachverhalt, aber den Sachverhalt gibt es doch zweifellos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für mich (und mein mich hier lenkendes Sprachempfinden) ruft

> totgetreten

das Bild vor Augen, dass der Tod unmittelbar eintritt, oder dass solange aktiv und unablässig getreten wird, bis das Opfer tot ist.

Insofern finde ich die Wortwahl für die beschriebene Situation eigentlich falsch. Sie ist aber in einer Zeitung wohl auch entschuldbar. Zeitungsspalten haben eine endliche Breite, da müssen auch gewissenhafte Redakteure manchmal Kompromisse machen. Schriebe man dagegen einen Roman (in dem man ja genügend Platz hat für die jeweils beste Formulierung), wäre "totgetreten" sicherlich ein Fehlgriff. Da müsste man dann schon etwas schreiben wie:

> Der Mops bekam einen kräftigen Tritt verpasst. Drei Tage später war er tot.

Was könnte man dagegen in einer Zeitung als Überschrift einer einspaltigen Meldung auf der bunten Seite - wo so eine Hundestory ja typischerweise erscheinen würde - machen? Vielleicht noch:

> Hund getreten - stirbt

Oder noch boulevardesker

> Hund getreten - tot

Wobei mir auffällt, dass die erste Überschrift den zeitlichen Abstand zwischen Getretenwerden und Dahinscheiden klar vor Augen führt, während die zweite Überschrift schon wieder das Problem hat, dass man spontan zu verstehen meint, dass der Hund das Zeitliche sofort - im unmittelbaren Anschluss an den Tritt -  gesegnet hat. Also ist "Hund getreten - stirbt" für mich in diesem Fall die bessere Überschrift.

#### Grau ist alle Theorie

Ich kann hier noch die Mitteilung machen, dass in der kleinen Stadt, aus der ich komme, die Geschichte kolportiert wird, dass einmal ein junger Mann aus der damaligen ländlichen Hippie-Szene in Holzschuhen den samstäglichen Wochenmarkt besuchte, wo es immer sehr eng zugeht, und dort, wie es üblich ist, mit Bekannten im Plausch vertieft im Kreise stehend, unachtsam einen Schritt nach hinten tat, wobei ein kleines Hündlein, das gerade vorbeigeführt wurde, unter den Holzschuh geriet. Das Hündlein war sofort tot.

Die Überschrift müsste dann heißen

> Hund mit Holzschuh zertreten

Answer (score 9):

tottreten heisst: durch treten töten.
Im Fokus liegt die Kausalität.

So gilt z.B. in der EU ein Mensch, der innerhalb von 30 Tagen an den Folgen eines Verkehrsunfalls stirbt, als ein Verkehrstoter. Die Unmittelbarkeit muss nicht gegeben sein.
Siehe: [GBE-BUND](http://www.gbe-bund.de/glossar/Verkehrstote.html)

Comment: Natürlich muss die Unmittelbarkeit gegeben sein, was juristisch hier der Fall ist. Denn es bedeutet nur, dass sozusagen nichts damitten liegt - zwischen Tat und Ergebnis - das auf das Ergebnis Einfluss genommen hätte oder hätte nehmen können. Bspw: Der Hundehalter übersieht die Schwere der Folgen und geht nicht zum Arzt, ein gebrochenes Bein entzündet sich und führt zur tödlichen Sepsis.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist nebensächlich, ob der Tod noch während des Tretens eintritt, egal welches Kopfkino da gerade bei einigen Kommentatoren stattfindet.

Laut Duden ist **tottreten**: *durch (darauf) Treten töten*.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tottreten

Das "durch" deutet auf eine Ursächlichkeit hin, aber nicht unbedingt auf  Unmittelbarkeit. Dass es da vielleicht juristische Unterschiede gibt, ist auch unerheblich. Juristen würden das sowieso wohl anders formulieren.

Also war die Überschrift m.E. völlig korrekt.

*Nehmen wir mal was analoges: "grun und blau schlagen". Da wird auch nicht so lange geschlagen, bis der andere grün oder blau ist. Das kommt erst später. Die Ursächlichkeit ist hier durschschlaggebend.*

*Oder "erschießen": Da muss derjenige, der erschossen wird, auch nicht sofort tot sein. Was gilt, ist, dass der Schuss die Ursache für den Tod war.*

Das geiche gilt auch für "Sattessen"

Comment: Gerade für Zeitungsüberschriften ist durchaus relevant, welches Bild beim Leser sich durch die Wortwahl spontan von einer Situation ergibt. Eine formalistische Reduktion auf kurze Bedeutungserklärungen in einem Rechtschreib-Katalog ist da nicht sinnvoll. In anderen Textgattungen mag man den intuitiven Aspekt der Wortwahl hintanstellen und mehr auf Formales abheben. (Aber auch dann wäre der Rechtschreib-Duden vermutlich keine ausreichende Referenz.)

Comment: Die Definition passt doch gar nicht. Es geht nicht um einen Käfer oder so, der totgetreten wurde, indem jemand _auf_ ihn _trat_, sondern um ein Lebewesen, dem - nicht notwendigerweise von oben, also von oben auf ihn drauf - Tritte verpasst wurden. Das sind völlig verschiedene Vorgänge. Auch wenn _darauf_ in der Definition in Klammern steht, scheint der Duden sich ja nur auf den einen speziellen Vorgang zu beziehen.

Comment: @Christian: Vielleicht. Aber das Kopfkino einzelner, die den Hund sofort sterben sehen, ist da eher irrelevant. Wenn ich jemanden totschieße (erschieße), bedeutet das auch nicht, dass er sofort tot sein muss, oder? Was gilt, ist dass er durch meinen Schuss getötet wurde.

Comment: @Björn: denk an anderen, ähnlichen Wörtern. Wenn ich jemanden erschieße, muss er auch nicht sofort tot sein. Er ist durch meinen Schuss gestorben, sofort oder z.B. im Krankenhaus. Mein Schuss war ursächlich. Nur darum geht es. Gleiches gilt für Tottreten.

Comment: @Björn: deswegen steht "darauf" auch in Klammern.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, dass du recht hast. Aber sieh es doch mal aus der Perspektive des Autors: Wie würdest du eine korrekte Schlagzeile formulieren? 
Für den durchschnittlichen Zeitungsleser ist es denke ich nicht von Bedeutung, ob der Hund nun unmittelbar oder später verstorben ist. Ein Mensch hat durch rohe Gewalt ein Tier getötet. Das ist die Kernaussage, die vermittelt werden soll.

Comment: Naja, wie _ich_ eine korrekte Schlagzeile formulieren würde, ist irrelevant, auch wenn die Vorschläge von @O. R. Mapper schon in die richtige Richtung gehen. Die Frage ist eher, ob ein _Zeitungsredakteur_ Schlagzeilen formulieren darf, die den Tatsachen widersprechen. In dem Artikel über den Hund sind wir angesichts des grausamen Themas nachsichtig. Aber man stelle sich ein beliebiges anderes Thema vor.

Comment: Ich verstehe, dass es nicht faktisch korrekt ist. Da Tiere aber keine Rechtssubjekte sind, ist es auch juristisch nicht erheblich, ob es nun Totschlag, Mord oder Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge ist. 

> Aber man stelle sich ein beliebiges anderes Thema vor.

Das ist hier nicht relevant - Dammbruchargument

Comment: Hier spricht ein ehemaliger Zeitungsredakteur: Ja, das Ziel wird sein, inhaltlich zu 100 Prozent korrekte Überschriften zu finden, jedenfalls in einer seriösen Zeitung (nicht alle sind ja solche). Ich finde ebenfalls, dass "totgetreten" eine andere Szene vor Augen ruft als etwa "getreten und später daran gestorben", aber ich habe auch Verständnis dafür, dass Zeitungsspalten nunmal eine endliche Breite und Zeitungsredaktionen einen Redaktionsschluss haben. Beides kann dazu führen, dass Überschriften entstehen, die, hätte man mehr Platz und mehr Zeit, vielleicht anders ausgefallen wären.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, du kannst das gern als Antwort schreiben.

Comment: @Björn - Hmm... ja... aber die Frage war ja, ob "totgetreten" den Sachverhalt korrekt beschreibt (die Antwort wäre wohl: nein, eigentlich nicht), und mein Kommentar geht darauf überhaupt nicht ein sondern richtet den Blick eher auf Begleitumstände nicht ganz sachverhaltsgemäßer Wortwahl in Zeitungsüberschriften.

Answer (score 1):

Der Denkfehler ist "unmittelbar". Es muss einfach nur ursächlich sein, und man kann es dann so sagen.

Das ist analog zu "sattgegessen". Man isst, hört auf und ist eine halbe Stunde später satt, nachdem das Sättigungsgefühl eingetreten ist, und antwortet dann mit "Danke, bin noch sattgegessen".

Comment: Mit derselben Herangehensweise könnte ich auf deine Ansicht reagieren mit: "Der Denkfehler ist die Nicht-Unmittelbarkeit. Es muss ja nicht ursächlich sein, und man kann es dann so sagen." Also wie kommst du darauf? Gibt es Quellen? Wieso ist deine "Denkweise" die Richtige und meine nicht?

Comment: Totgetreten kann bedeuten, dass der Hund getreten wurde und dadurch jetzt tot ist. Also ist "totgetreten" nicht falsch. Die Unmittelbarkeit muss nicht gegeben sein.

Comment: Ohne Belege, Querverweise o.ä. ist das meiner Meinung nach keine Antwort.

Comment: @Burki: Das ist ja wohl Unsinn. Was für Querverweise, usw.? Es ist ja völlig klar was "totgetreten" bedeutet.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, naja, also offensichtlich gibt es ja verschiedene Ansichten, weshalb man nicht von _völlig klar_ sprechen kann.. Was für mich, und offensichtlich auch für andere, bisher _völlig klar_ war, scheint es für dich, und wiederum für andere, nicht zu sein und umgekehrt. Doch während ich begründet habe, sehe ich in dieser Antwort nichts dergleichen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Unsinn ist, Behauptungen in die Welt zu stellen ohne sie zu begründen. "weil ich es sage" ist übrigens keine Begründung, sondern bestenfalls dummes Zeug.

Comment: Man sagt auch sattgegessen, obwohl der Sättigungseffekt nicht unmittelbar auftritt, sondern zeitverzögert. Dafür muss ich als Muttersprachler doch keinen wissenschaftlichen Beleg bringen.

Comment: @äüö: Hier tritt dasselbe Problem auf. Habe ich mich _satt gegessen_, dann heißt das für mich, dass ich solange gegessen habe, bis ich satt war.

Comment: @Björn: Und wenn deine Mutti dich fragt, ob du dich schön sattgegessen hast, antwortest du dann gegebenfalls "Nein, ich hatte schon vor dem Eintritt des Sättigungsgefühls aufgehört zu essen."? LOL ;)

Comment: @Burki: man muss nicht für alles Querverweise haven, nur um zu sehen ob etwas richtig ist oder nicht. So funktioniert das nicht im Leben.Und nicht jede offensichtliche Behauptung braucht noch extra Beweise. M.E. ist sowas wie "aber das gilt nicht ohne Querverweise" oft eine Taktik um eine offensichtlich wahre Behauptung zu diskreditieren.

Comment: @Burki "weil ich es sage" ist tatsächlich ohne Gewicht. Aber "weil es offensichtlich so ist" sagt schon mehr.

Comment: @Björn: Wenn jemand erschossen wird, muss er auch nicht sofort tot sein. Wichtig ist, dass der Schuss ursächlich für den Tod war. Gleiches gilt für Tottrete oder Sattessen, oder noch mehr für grün und blau schlagen. Man schlägt nicht, bis jemand grün oder blau ist. Diese Farben kommen erst später. Das Schlagen ist allerdings die Ursache. Bei diesen Begriffen geht es um Ursache, nicht um Zeit.

Comment: Nein, @äüö, ich würde es eben **nicht** sagen, wenn ich _vor_ dem Eintritt des Sättigungsgefühls aufgehört hätte, zu essen, sondern höchstens, wenn ich aufgehört hätte zu essen, _als_ oder _nachdem_ das Sättigungsgefühl eingesetzt hat. Ich erläutere doch schon die ganze Zeit, dass, meiner Meinung nach, die Handlung (hier Essen) erst bei oder nach Eintreten des Zustands (hier Sattsein) abgeschlossen sein muss.

Comment: Letzter Versuch: Totschlag ist im Strafrecht auch nicht definiert mit der Bedingung, dass geschlagen wurde bis zum Eintritt des Todes, sondern es muss nur zum Tod geführt haben. Wenn das nicht einleuchtet, geb ich's auf. Ich fürchte dann um die Professionalität von German Stackexchange. :-(

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ich komme aus der Mathematik, und dort gilt, dass du beweisen musst, dass deine Aussage wahr ist. Hier verlange ich ja nicht mal einen harten Beweis, aber zumindest eine schlüssige Begründung, warum deine Antwort richtig ist, wäre sehr hilfreich. Sonst bleiben wir beim "Du liegst falsch" - "Nein, du liegst falsch" stecken. Aber deine Beispiele mit dem grün- und blauschlagen gehen ja endlich in die Richtung :-)

Comment: @Björn. ja, das gilt für akademische Beweise. Hier handelt es sich nur darum. ob der Tod direkt einsetzen muss, oder nicht. Das ist keine akademische Abhandlung. Hier reicht der gesunde Menschenverstand und die Erfahrung. Begründung: vergleiche es mit totschießen. Auch wenn derjenige nicht sofort stribt, wurde er trotzdem totgeschossen. Der Hund wurde totgetreten (also durch Treten getötet). Was soll "tottreten" sonst bedeuten?

Comment: @äüö: Es ist schon merkwürdig, ich tue nichts anderes als Beweise, schlüssige Begründungen oder wenigstens Erläuterungen einzufordern, weil das für mich zur einer professionellen Beantwortung einer Frage einfach dazugehört, und gerade Sie, dessen Antwort eine einfache Behauptung enthält, fürchten um die Professionalität von German Stackexchange.

Comment: Begründungen und Erläuterungen wurden hier in den Kommentaren genug geliefert. Wenn Sie aus der Mathematik kommen, kennen sie vielleicht die Phrase "wie man leicht sieht"...